# Could my Behemoth exist?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures

roaming vast deserts some characteristics of my [Behemoths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behemoth) include:

- being as large as [Paraceratherium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraceratherium)
- having slightly longer forelimbs than hindlimbs
- are herbivores
- having a warthog like mane
- having a bison like head
- having elephant like tusks
- having a long tail (optional)

Given these characteristics, what species could the Behemoth have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to such a being?

NOTE: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: Anatomically correct series... once again...

Comment: icewar1908 you have submitted a lot of these in a very short time.  I like your enthusiasm but consider pacing yourself.  A little time in between might find readers  rested and more enthusiastic for your next.

Comment: VTC: poor quality, as it's a copy-paste of other questions. Make this about your world or make it of use & interest to others!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So basically a steppe mammoth.

[image: ![enter image description here]

They fulfill all your criteria

-Herbivore, check

-Front limbs longer than back limbs, big check

-Tusks, huge check

-Long tail, well long for a large mammal, plus there is no reason you could not use a slighlty modified one with a longer tail, just say it is sexual selection.

-Ox like head, well minus horns anyway.

-Similiar in size to  *Paraceratherium*, check (see below)

[image: ![enter image description here]

they already roamed a near desert, the [steppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steppe), not all deserts are hot, but adapting them for a hotter setting is easy, elephants already live in the savannah. the ability to find and dig for water makes elephants very good at dealing with dry conditions. the fact they can knock down tree to eat everything on them helps.  As a bonus they coexisted with humans so having them still around is not a big stretch.

If you don't want to use mammoths exactly. try basing it on our good friend *Dienotherium*, nearly the same size,  there are several other very weird *Proboscidea* to choose from.

[image]

I also feel I should share [some art](https://www.tumblr.com/search/steppe%20mammoth) of someone who has taken a slightly fantasy variant on mammoths you may find appealing.

Comment: thanks but i wonder if it might to lose some of its hair to cope with the hot desert.

Comment: Like I said elephants like in hot arid environments just lose hte hair and make the ears bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be cheeky but. . .

Your Behemoths evolved from **Paraceratherium (Indricotherium)**

[image]

The main difficulty is these guys living in the desert. Presumably they roamed the savanah where there was much more food for a large animal. Modern desert animals tend to be small.

I propose they do not live full-time in the desert but are migratory. They move from savanah to savanah, eating everything in sight and then making week-long voyages through the desert to the next location. Their size helps with these voyages, where they go a long time without eating or drinking. The tusks evolved first for digging up roots, and then for upending entire trees so they can eat the entire thing bark and all. The other changes needed are largely cosmetic.

Comment: Cheeky! ...I see what you did there...

Comment: @DavidHambling: Huh?

Comment: that species was mentioned in the question...

Comment: Paraceratherium do not have tusks.

Comment: @John: Cool, edited!